# mysql create procedure script

Tags: mysql, insert, procedure

I am a bit confused with mysql create procedure script.
My script looks like as follows:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE play;
CREATE PROCEDURE play()
BEGIN
insert into hi (name,id)VALUES ('apple','2010');
END
//
```

It does not insert into table hi.

Comment: You need to explain a little more than that. Is this script not working, or does it not insert when you call the PROCEDURE, do you get an error?

Comment: I figure out how to insert now. I do not use "create procedure". It can work. Now My problem how to use procedure to do?

Comment: It seems that you are under the impression that the above script (by itself) would insert values. The above script only creates the procedure, you need to call the procedure afterwards, to execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script does not actually [execute the `play` procedure via `call` command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/call.html)

You need to add

`call play`

command

Answer (score 0):

use

```
CALL play();
```

and I suggest use

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS play()
```

instead DROP PROCEDURE play()

Comment: What does it adds to the previously accepted answer? Why you recommend the `IF EXISTS play()`? Comments will be useful for others looking for an answer to have a better understanding of your code